Spring oauth2 client with authorization_code principal name
I have a web service providing a variety of features to logged in users, running Java Spring Boot. I am adding a new feature that requires this web service to communicate with an external resource server, accessing resources specific to the logged in user. The resource server is using OAuth2. Google drive for purposes of this question, but I will need to integrate multiple clients for different resource servers.
I am trying to get an authorization_code flow to work with an Oauth2 clent and Spring Security and I don't understand how to make it work because it doesn't seem to be able to link requests with my authenticated users.
My understanding is, the flow should be

A user authenticated to my service tries to access a Google Drive resource
My service redirects the user to Google's Oauth2 flow
User gives permission, Google's server redirect back to GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK URL that I configured with a code and state
Spring security should now process the redirect, take the code and state, convert them into access and refresh tokens, and store those in authorized client repository linked to the user.

It's the last step that is failing - OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter stores the data under anonymousUser instead of the logged in user
My client configuration is
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <SECRET>
            client-secret: <SECRET?
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri:  http://... // same as GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK constant in code
            scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
        provider:
          google:
            authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
            token-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

My security configuration is
  auth
    .requestMatchers(GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK)
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();

I can make the initial call to my service, it redirects to Google, Google's flow works and redirects back to GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK url value. When Google's flow redirects back to my service, the bearer token header that my web service is using for authentication is no longer there. I had to declare GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK as not requiring authentication in the configuration above.
Now, the callback comes in, the Oauth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter picks it up, finds the original request, resolves it and gets to this point in the code Spring security GitHub Source
String principalName = (currentAuthentication != null) ? currentAuthentication.getName() : "anonymousUser";

In my setup currentAuthentication turns out to be null and therefore the tokens aren't stored as associated with the current user.
It seems I am missing something about how the system should work - how can the callback request coming from Google's server be authenticated and linked to the user who issued the original request, before the series of redirects?
I'm assuming that there's some setup that is possible to preserve the user principal through those redirects but I cannot figure out what may be missing in my system.


the bearer token header that my web service is using

This means that your app is configured as a resource server, probably stateless (no session). Running an authorization code flow like you're doing with oauth2Login is a client business and requires sessions.
This also means that you should already have an OAuth2 client somewhere: something that gets tokens from an authorization server and then sets the Authorization header with a Bearer when sending (or forwarding) requests to your "service".
As your resource server should remain stateless, I see two options, both requiring the already existing OAuth2 client to manage the user's Google identity (in addition to the identity he already has on your authorization server):

the OAuth2 client directly calls the Google API and presents the result to the user or sends it to your "service" for further processing.
the OAuth2 client sends Google's access token to your "service" as a custom header (the access token from "your" authorization server still being used in Authorization header). Your service can then authorize its own requests to Google API with the value it gets from the custom header.

How to define a second registration in your OAuth2 client, get a second token set, and position such a custom header depends on the framework you use (and we have no info about what your client is).

Thanks, that's very helpful, I didn't realise that Spring Security relied on sessions for this.
My system architecture is

A central identity service
A React web app front end
My stateless service

The web frontend logs in with the central service, gets  bearer token and uses it for auth with my service. Unfortunately I cannot change the auth service, not under my control. I also cannot call Google APIs from web FE because it needs to be part of a BE transaction.
If I were to send an access token as a custom header, are there security risks here?

What I was actually hoping to work out is an approach seen in Slack etc where there is first a "connect to Google Drive" flow during which the user gives permissions, and from that point forward the app is authorized. I know I'd need to come up with a DB authorized client storage for persistence. I could do something similar with your second suggestion - authorize from FE, pass on access+refresh to BE, manually create an authorized client with those and save it into the authorized store. But I think I'd get tripped by PKCE there because the original authorization from browser would require it.

It is not recommended anymore to configure single-page and mobile apps as OAuth2 clients. So, you should probably change your architecture, unless your React app is a Next.js app using NextAuth lib. Follow the link in section 1 of this article I wrote for the why, section 2 for the recommended alternative description, and the rest of the article for implementation.

In your case, I'd define two registrations with authorization_code on the BFF (one for your authorization server and the other for Google). I'd put two buttons to initiate these flows from the React app (for instance a "login" and a "link Google account"), and last write a web filter or something to have the BFF set a custom header with Google access token when the authorized client manager can provide one. The tokens would be present only on requests internal to your backend.
